# How to deduce the following map between Zariski tangent spaces is surjective?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of schemes: $X$, $Y$ are regular schemes, let $Z_1, Z_2$ be two closed regular subschemes of $Y$, let $x \in X \times_Y Z_2$ such that $y = f(x) \in Z_1 \cap Z_2$. 
Then I would like to know how I can deduce that the map
$$
T_xX \rightarrow (T_yY/T_yZ_2) \otimes_{k(y)} k(x)
$$
is surjective knowing that

1) the image of  $T_{x} (X \times_Y Z_1)$  generates $T_yY/T_yZ_2$

2) $T_x(X \times_Y Z_1) \rightarrow T_y Z_1 \otimes_{k(y)} k(x)$ is surjective.

It is supposed to follow from these things but not seeing how... I would appreciate any explanation on this. Thank you!

Comment: $f(x)\in Y$, but $Z_1\cap Z_2\subset X$, so did you mean something else?

Comment: @Mohan Typo fixed. Thank you.

Comment: Is there supposed to be a $\otimes_{k(y)} k(x)$ in 1)? Why is it missing there when it is included in the other two?

Comment: @WillSawin It is not there because I just wrote it as it is written in the paper I am looking at...

Comment: It seems crucial to the issue, because $T_x( X times_Y Z_1)$ is a subspace of $T_x X$, hence 1) should be sufficient to prove the statement unless something very strange is going on with the tensor products.

Comment: @WillSawin I would be happy with a solution with your suggestion. The wording in the paper does suggest that it is not too complicated..

Comment: @TakeshiGouda Which paper?

Comment: This is the paper https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00039-016-0381-8

Comment: The specific part of the paper regarding this question is Proposition 2.5 on page 1455, first/second paragraph of the proof.